# Entity Reference Module > Undefined & Non-Object Crashes

Tags: entities

## Preface

I have a fresh site install of Drupal. I'm fairly new to Drupal, but I feel rather confident with anything but module hacking right now. I've just finished about a month+ of editing and tweaking a play site to get comfortable with the Drupal theme engine and feel I am ready to move on. So I started putting together a real site using Drupal (rather than my play one).

I installed Entity API, Entity Reference, Views, and a few more.

### Goal

My goal is to create **Video Tutorials** (*custom content*) that are listed inside **Tutorials** (*custom content*). This way I can create several **Video Tutorials** and use them in one, or more, **Tutorials**.

### Attempts

I checked into Node Embed, which would theoretically work much better for this, but I have since given up as Node Embed requires installing and configuring an outside (non-drupal) plugin and the last time I tried to get that WYSIWYG editor installed it took me forever and I don't want the hassle.

## Issue

I have just attempted to create the **Video Tutorials** and **Tutorials** custom contents.

> I created **Video Tutorials** first. I have not edited the custom content fields. It has the generic fields for now.
>
> Then I proceeded to create the **Tutorial** custom content type. I created a new field for it [field_tutorial_videos] that is supposed to be an Entity Reference to **Video Tutorials**.

The problem is I get this error block as soon as I create that field and it shows up everytime I click to edit this field...

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nid in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 619 of .../sites/all/modules/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$vid in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 620 of .../sites/all/modules/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access() (line 620 of .../sites/all/modules/entity/modules/callbacks.inc).
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nid in node_access() (line 3002 of .../modules/node/node.module).

I have read through the README on both ENTITY API and ENTITY REFERENCE and I get nothing that makes sense. I have no idea what to do from here.

Comment: Having problem with entity_metadata_no_hook_node_access... too. I think this thread might help https://drupal.org/node/1780646